# Powershell Script Host

Tags: powershell

I have a script to retrieve a list of groups using Powershell. I guess these are the groups of the default hosts.

I want to set another host different to the default host and get all groups of this host. How can I achieve this?

My script is quite simple.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Get-Adgroup -Filter * | Select Name, Description
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: "I guess these are the groups of the default hosts" - no, these are Active Directory groups, you can't use `Get-ADGroup` to retrieve local computer groups

Comment: To solve these things I use the [adsi] provider in PowerShell